# Override JqGrid header click or implement JqGrid header double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, jqgrid

In my Asp.Net web application I am using JqGrid using jQuery.

JqGrid is providing sorting functionality on column header click, but I have one specific requirement: I want to implement column header double click and call custom JavaScript function to display result/message below JqGrid(not in footer, out of grid area), custom message depends on which column user has double clicked.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you can do that, be strong !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jqGrid header are stored in  tag.
So You need just simmply take the id of jqGrid and set the double click event and take on div tag and append it in the grid with your require message.

```
$("#id-of-your-grid th").dbclick(function() {...});
```

Comment: Thanks @shakyl mansuri for quick response, yes I registered th double click event on gridComplet event, the only road-block was sorting, actually as sorting was enabled on grid column double click was not working, but we have more priority for double click so we disabled sorting and it worked :)